# Helm template variables are nil

Tags: templates, go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm trying to use a template to pull values from values.yaml, concatenate them into a CSV list. Here's an example of my solution.

values.yaml:

```
testValue1: "string1"
testValue2: "String2"
credentials: 
- c1: "string3"
- c2: "string4"
```

_helpers.tpl:

```
{{- define "test.template" -}}
{{- $value1 := .Values.testValue1 -}}
{{- $value2 := .Values.testValue2 -}}
{{- $credentials := "" -}}
{{- range $index, $cred := .Values.credentials -}}
{{- $credentials = $cred "," $credentials -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- printf "%s,%s,%s" $value1 $value2 $credentials -}}
{{- end -}}
```

test.yaml

```
templatedValue: {{ template "test.template" }}
```

When I run `helm template --output-dir outputs chart` I get:

test.yaml

```
templatedValue: %!s(<nil>),%!s(<nil>),
```

both the variables I set as values are nil, and the `credentials` are just an empty string. If I put the values in the values.yaml directly into the `test.yaml` file it works fine. So I'm not sure why I'm getting these nil values from the template. There's other templates in the `_helpers.tpl` which grab values from the values.yaml file, so I'm not sure why my template doesn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
helm version: 
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.3", GitCommit:"0e7f3b6637f7af8fcfddb3d2941fcc7cbebb0085", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.3", GitCommit:"0e7f3b6637f7af8fcfddb3d2941fcc7cbebb0085", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Comment: The `{{ template "test.template" }}` action executes `"test.template"` but does not pass any parameters to it. So inside `test.template` the pipeline `.Values` is invalid.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. There are other templates in the _helpers.tpl file which read from the values file just fine: 
`{{- define "chart.name" -}}
 {{- default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
 {{- end -}}`
It has no parameters in it either eh?

Comment: What matters is how you call the template. How is `"chart.name"` called? I'm sure there are parameters passed to it when calling it.

Comment: Ah. it's called with `{{ include "chart.name" . }}`. So should I do similar for my `test.template` template?

Comment: Yes, try to pass the dot `.` if you have no other info what to pass, e.g. `{{ template "test.template" . }}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{{ template "test.template" }}` action executes `"test.template"` template but does not pass any parameters to it. So inside `test.template` the pipeline will be `<nil>` and so `.Values` is invalid.

Quoting from [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/):

> ```
> {{template "name"}}
>   The template with the specified name is executed with nil data.
>
> {{template "name" pipeline}}
>   The template with the specified name is executed with dot set
>   to the value of the pipeline.
> ```

You have to pass something in `{{template}}`. If you have no other info what to pass, try passing the dot `.`, the current pipeline.

```
{{ template "test.template" . }}
```